# Proving that $T_1T_2$, $P_1P_2$, and $MN$ are concurrent.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The question is:

> Given a trapezium $ABCD$ where $AB$ is parallel with $CD$ and $AD$ is not parallel with $BC$. Lines $AD$ and $BC$ intersect at $E$ while $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $F$. The circumcircle of $\triangle ECF$ cuts the extension of $CD$ at $T_1$ where $T_1\neq C$, while the circumcircle of $\triangle EFB$ cuts the extension of $AB$ at $T_2$ where $T_2\neq B$. The line $ET_1$ cuts $AB$ at $P_2$ And line $ET_2$ cuts $CD$ at $P_1$. It is known that $BT_1$ and $CP_2$ meets at $M$ while $AP_1$ and $DT_2$ meets at $N$. Prove that $P_1P_2$, $T_1T_2$, and $MN$ meets at one point.

How do I solve this question? How do I prove that three lines are concurrent?

Here’s the figure I’ve made in Geogebra.

[image]

Comment: Why not adding a drawing?

Comment: Ah, alright. I will

Answer (score 1):

Since $P_2T_2$ and $DC$ are parallel, and $ET_1CF$ is cyclic, we have:

$$\angle EP_2A=\angle P_2T_1C=\angle EFA.$$

So, $EAFP_2$ is cyclic, and $P_2$ is the intersection of the circumcircle of $\triangle EAF$ and the extension of $AB.$

Similarly,

$$\angle EP_1D=\angle ET_2B=\angle EFB.$$

So, $EFDP_1$ is cyclic, and $P_1$ is the intersection of the circumcircle of $\triangle EDF$ and the extension of $DC.$

Now, note that:

$$\angle T_2FE=\angle T_2BE\\ \angle T_1FE=\angle ECT_1\\ \implies \angle T_2FE+\angle T_1FE=180^{\circ}.$$

Therefore, $T_1T_2$ passes through $F$. A very similar argument proves that $P_1P_2$ also passes through $F$ because of what we showed earlier.

To be done, we just need to show that $M, F, N$ are collinear.

Now that we know that $T_1T_2$ and $P_1P_2$ meet at $F$, we apply the **Pappus's hexagon theorem** (you may take a look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem)).

Consider the two triples $(T_2, A, P_2)$ and $(P_1, D, T_1)$ (as two sets of collinear points). By the Pappus's hexagon theorem, we know that $N$, $F$, $AT_1 \cap DP_2$ are collinear.

Moreover, the two triples $(A, B, P_2)$ and $(D, C, T_1)$ imply that $M$, $F$, $AT_1 \cap DP_2$ are collinear.

Having the two results together means that $M$, $N$, $F$ are also collinear.

We are done.